# Apache Tomcat reject post request for more than 19KB and return 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: tomcat, java, springboot, springframework

Spring boot application deployed on apache **tomcat** 9 reject post request larger than 19kb.

the *bookController*:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/book")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookController {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookController.class);
    
    private final BookServices bookServices;
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")  @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void addBook(@Valid @RequestBody BookModel bookModel) throws SanprException {
        try {
            logger.info("success...");
            bookServices.addBook(bookModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Failed...");
            throw new SanprException(message.toString(), e, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

the *bookModel* class :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookModel {    
        @Id
        private long id;
        private String title;
        private boolean isPublish;
        private boolean isDuplicated;
        private MediaModel background;
        private String pdfFile;
        private String description;
        private List<TableContentsModel> tableContents;
        private GlobalReferentialModel level;
        private GlobalReferentialModel type;

}
```

here my **server.xml** configuration for apache tomcat,

```
 <Connector port="8010" 
            protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            compression="on" 
            compressionMinSize="2048"
            maxPostSize="26214400" maxHttpHeaderSize="26214400"
            maxSavePostSize="-1"    
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"
            address="*.*.*.*"
            redirectPort="8443"
            useIPVHosts="true" />
```

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
           acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
           disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" 
           maxThreads="25"  port="8443" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" maxSwallowSize = "-1" 
           maxHttpHeaderSize="819200" 
           keystoreFile="....keystore" keystorePass="****"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
           secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" compression="on" SSSLVerifyClient="none" />
```

here scrrenshots on **postman** testing :

working : https://ibb.co/0K679Hf

not working : https://ibb.co/4JG2WSR

Comment: Check your application's logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton as the app is deployed on tomcat so in the log '400  bad req'  doesn't appear

Comment: Then it would be in something like catalina.out or wherever you configured Tomcat to log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what will log helps ! here the log on catalina of two diffrent request 
https://ibb.co/PNm0DYt